# Hiding Columns based on a Cell Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to hide columns based on the selection in A2. [image]

Here is the code I am working with and I am hard stuck.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:J"); 

  //Let's get the row & column indexes of the active cell
  var row = e.range.getRow(1);
  var col = e.range.getColumn(0);

  //Check that your active cell is within your named range
  if (col >= myRange.getColumn() && col <= myRange.getLastColumn() && row >= myRange.getRow() && row <= myRange.getLastRow()) { 
    if e.myRange === "Renewal" ? myRange.hideColumns(5)
    
  }
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question does not seem clear enough to properly answer. The current code has syntax errors and will throw every time a value is edited in columns A:J in any sheet. It would make more sense to tell what you are trying to do rather than asking for help with your current attempted solution. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I assume you want to hide column 5 (E) if dropdown in A2 is "Renewal". If that's what you want, then you got many issues in your script.

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // get current sheet
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  // get row and column of edited cell
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  // make sure to only hide/show column if edited cell is A2 in 'Sheet1'
  if (col == 1 && row == 2 && sheet.getSheetName() == 'Sheet1') { 
    // if value of A2 in Sheet1 is Renewal, hide columns, if not Renewal, then show the same columns back
    if (e.value === "Renewal") {
      sheet.hideColumns(5, 2); // hide column 5-6 (E-F)
      sheet.hideColumns(8, 1); // hide column 8 (H) 
    }
    else {
      sheet.showColumns(5, 2); // show column 5-6 (E-F)
      sheet.showColumns(8, 1); // show column 8 (H) 
    }
  }
}
```

#### Mistakes:

- `getRow()` and `getColumn()` gets the current row and column of the range respectively. You don't pass a parameter here
- You do not need to identify if your edited cell is within the range A:J, you only need to specify that row and column should be pointing to A2 (and a specific sheet if needed be which is considered in )
- Ternary operators do not need `if` statement before it and it always need the else part. Thus I added `showColumns` to show the hidden column if A2 is not Renewal.
- `hideColumns()` is a sheet method, not range, thus you need to get the sheet you currently edit. Additionally, it accepts 2 parameters, the index where it starts hiding a column and how many columns you need hidden.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Resources:

- [getRow/getColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)
- [hideColumns/showColumns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)
- [Ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I checked out the resources this weekend I understand where I went wrong. If I would want to hide more columns would I just another if for the columns. For example, would I do another ```e.value === "Renewal" ? sheet.hideColumns(5, 1) : sheet.showColumns(5, 1)``` for each column I want to hide?  I looked at the reference for hiding columns and I only see if it is sequential.

Comment: I have modified my answer @KyleCole. Please see the updated code. use normal `if-else` statement instead of ternary as ternary is not built for multiple commands if the statement is true/false. If the statement is true, it will execute all commands inside the `{` `}` under `if`.

Comment: I created a new line for each column and it workes. I will switch to the updated code.

Comment: @KyleCole, it will still run if using multiple ternary but it isn't optimized since all of them have the same condition, just combine them like the updated code above and it will also look much cleaner and easy to understand.

Also, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)